# Как сделать оповещения/уведомление на php?

Tags: php

Нужно на строне сервера сделать всплывающее оповещение/уведомление на рабочем столе.

Т.е. клиент кликает на кнопочку у себя в браузере (добавил запись в бд), а на строне сервера появляется всплывающее уведомление о новой записи в бд.

Comment: Вроде этого http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hCwyv, но чтоб воспроизводилось на сервере

Comment: То есть Вы хотите, чтобы после записи в БД у клиента отображалось соответствующее уведомление или оно должно отображаться у администратора ресурса в его админ панели или как?... Поясните вопрос пожалуйста.

Comment: Вопрос требует уточнения. На сервере есть GUI и кто-то будет сидеть на сервере в GUI и должно быть уведомление в этом GUI, или на сервере будет кто-то сидеть в браузере и в браузере на сервере должно быть уведомление? Или Вы не совсем понимаете что такое сервер ?

Comment: у админа чтоб отображалось

Comment: есть GUI,  вот этот пример показывает как имено это выглядит codepen.io/anon/pen/hCwyv

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант.

Отправлять по таймеру из админ панели AJAX'ом запрос к БД. Если появилось что-то новое, отправлять в админ панель соответствующую информацию и выводить уведомления.

Приблизительно, как-то так...

Comment: есть ли пример с ajax'ом какой-нибудь? Чтоб он в бд проверял новые записи

Comment: @pavel, дело в том, что пример реализации того, что я написал в ответе просто так за 5 минут не набросать. Либо пишите сами и, если что-то не получается выкладывайте Ваш код с конкретным описанием проблемы. Либо обращайтесь к фрилансерам, которые напишут Вам такой модуль для сайта, но уже за деньги. Только, если будете обращаться к ним, оформите Ваши пожелания в виде чёткого ТЗ, а не так как здесь. Иначе Вас вряд ли воспримут всерьёз.

Comment: Ок, спасибо что обьяснили суть)

Answer (score 0):

Отправляйте оповещения через Jabber (или другой мессенджер) или даже СМС-гейт. Таким образом админ может быть не привязан к рабочему столу.